# Killing/aborting a specific thread using it's ID in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, thread-abort

I need to terminate a specific Thread that I already know the Id of it, I get the ID by getting the 
`System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread`
and I already detect the thread ID that I need to terminate
what can I do to terminate it.

Comment: Are you trying to abort a thread running in another process?

Comment: Your question sounds like *how to shoot on my foot ?* Can you explain what you're trying to do instead? Why do you need to terminate a thread?

Comment: You've got a answer using `TerminateThread` [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28295713/2530848) . You can use it if you really know what it is doing and what are the consequences. It is unlikely you could know about the consequences of   `TerminateThread` when you're not aware of existence of such function.

Comment: @Gusdor that is how it read for me too...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using a couple P/Invoke methods. First off, call `OpenThread` on the thread with the ID you found to obtain a handle to it:

`IntPtr handle = OpenThread(THREADACCESS_SUSPEND_RESUME, false, (uint)thd.Id);`

Then call `SuspendThread` using the handle you just obtained:

```
if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
    var suspended = SuspendThread(threadHandle) == -1
```

That suspends the thread - ie. it will no longer be running. If you desperately want to kill it forcefully, you can call `TerminateThread` on the handle:

```
TerminateThread(handle, 0); // Or any other exit code.
```

Make sure to close the handle after you're done with it, for example inside a `finally` block if you're wrapping it in a try/catch.

As mentioned in the comments, terminating a thread forcefully like this is usually not what you want to do - be very careful when using this. *Suspending* a thread allows you to resume it at a later point, *Terminating* kills the thread immediately (read more [about why you shouldn't abort threads here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559255/whats-wrong-with-using-thread-abort))

Furthermore, the [MSDN documentation on TerminateThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686717(v=vs.85).aspx) mentions the following:

> TerminateThread is a dangerous function that should only be used in the most extreme cases. You should call TerminateThread only if you know exactly what the target thread is doing, and you control all of the code that the target thread could possibly be running at the time of the termination.

P/invokes:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll",SetLastError=true)]
static extern int SuspendThread(IntPtr hThread);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr OpenThread(ThreadAccess dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle,
   uint dwThreadId);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern bool TerminateThread(IntPtr hThread, uint dwExitCode);
```

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You're right, included `TerminateThread` as well.

Comment: A note: for those who wonder what the `ThreadAccess ` is — it's a just an `uint`.